# django rest framework -- how to stop child repetition at the root level

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am working with django's nested self referential objects and i have following `Category` model

```
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        qs = super(CategoryManager, self).filter(parent=None)
        return qs

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    # description_json = JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="sub_category", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    background_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="category-backgrounds", blank=True, null=True
    )

    objects = CategoryManager
```

for recursive representation i applied following serializers

```
class RecursiveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data

class CategoryListSerializer(ModelSerializer): 
    sub_category = RecursiveSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            # 'url',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'description',
            'parent',
            'background_image',
            'sub_category'
        )
```

and view,

```
class CategoryListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategoryListSerializer
```

its generate the following result.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Food",
        "slug": "food",
        "description": "",
        "parent": null,
        "background_image": null,
        "background_image_alt": "",
        "sub_category": [
            {
                "name": "Rice",
                "slug": "rice",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 20,
                "background_image": null,
                "background_image_alt": "",
                "sub_category": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Rice",
        "slug": "rice",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 20,
        "background_image": null,
        "background_image_alt": "",
        "sub_category": []
    }
]
```

Here the parent category `Food` has a child category `Rice` which is fine, but the problem is the child category `Rice` repeating at the root level, how can i stop this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `parent=None` to your queryset at the ViewSet level.

```
class CategoryListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
    serializer_class = CategoryListSerializer
```

Quite a clever solution with the recursive serializers! Only problem is it will generate *lots* of queries.  Depending on your database your a probably better off either:

1. Using a Recursive CTE ([a very good blog on it](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/01/exporting-a-hierarchy-in-json-with-recursive-queries/), returning json directly from postgres)
2. Query all records at once (if its a small table), build tree in python, and return the response directly.  Cache the response, and invalidate the cache record when an update/insert happens.

Note:

There isn't a really good reason to use `ListApiView` if you aren't supporting detail views (`/view/:pk/`) and filtering/pagination/sorting.  In that case you can just use an `APIView` with a `get()` method.

Comment: Its worked, Cool ! Also thanks for your extra effort adding valuable additional informations.